# how to get the substring

Tags: java, android

i have a string sssssh and i want to get the result as h only. it only can solve while i have another string ssssth and i will get th also without the s in front. whether i need to split it? can anyone help me?

i don't want to use - to separate by inserting the split coding since my string is like this.

before this i originally the string is h then i using String.format to insert ssss in front of the h. lastly i need to remove all the s and get the original string h.

```
String str1 = ssssh;
String result = h;
```

Comment: Why don't you just keep a reference to the original `String`?

Comment: Are you looking for the last character in a separate string?  Or removing the first N repeating characters?  Or everything before the first h?  Or something else?

Comment: @GabeSechan i want to remove the first N repeating characters and get the first character after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the String method to get the index of the last character 's':

```
int lastOccurenceOfS = str1.lastIndexOf("s");
```

Then you split your string from the next character forward:

```
String endString = str1.subString(lastOccurenceOfS + 1);
```

Comment: how about if my string is sssos
how can i get the result of os?

Comment: Then you need to parse the "s":s with a regexp

Comment: i am not so understand about it. i am a newbie on programming

Answer (score 0):

If what your asking is to split the h from all the other characters you can use this:

```
String str1 = "ssssh";
char ch = str1.charAt(str1.length() - 1);
```

Then what you are left with is the Char ch(h)